# Provide localization template without hard coding default values

Tags: java, android, xml, string

In my Android app, I have an XML file `/res/values/strings.xml` with default strings, like this snippet:

```
<string name="string_1">String 1</string>
<string name="string_2">String 2</string>
```

To encourage localization, I would like to provide **full** templates in other locales (such as `/res/values-es/strings.xml`).

For example, let's **imagine** Android supports a `@default` keyword. Then I can provide a full template as follows:

```
<string name="string_1">@default</string>
<string name="string_2">@default</string>
```

Such a provision may encourage localization by letting the translators merely input the translations and not have to worry about the XML file's completeness. They need not even be *tech-savvy*. They only need to search for the keyword and type in their translations.

If the above is possible, whenever I introduce a new string, I can place the string tag in all localization files without any translation. Translators can later on simply insert the missing translations and update the localization files. They are not shouldered with the responsibility of creating the XML tag.

**Is there a way to provide localized files with the strings falling back to the defaults even if they are defined?**

If I leave the string blank in the localized file (`<string name="string_1"></string>`), the localized app simply shows an empty string (does not fall back to the default string).

If I do a circular reference (`<string name="string_1">@string/string_1</string>`) the localized app shows a reference integer (`@2131099667`).

It seems the only way is to place an exact copy of the default strings in the localized files:

```
<string name="string_1">String 1</string>
<string name="string_2">String 2</string>
```